# Bash script multiple string variable comparisons

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to compare 3 set then I write a bash script but the result is wrong.
please guide me

```
#!/bin/bash
function SCORETYPE {
if [[ "$ENG1" < "$ENG2" || "$ENG3" < "$ENG4" || "$ENG5" > "$ENG6" ]]; then
    STYPE="A"
elif [[ "$ENG1" < "$ENG2" || "$ENG3" > "$ENG4" || "$ENG5" > "$ENG6" ]]; then
    STYPE="B"
elif [[ "$ENG1" > "$ENG2" || "$ENG3" < "$ENG4" || "$ENG5" < "$ENG6" ]]; then
    STYPE="C"
else
    STYPE="D"
fi

echo "$STYPE"
}

# DATA for  A
ENG1=10; ENG2=15; ENG3=5; ENG4=7; ENG5=45; ENG6=15
echo -n "Correct is A -- Answer is = "; SCORETYPE

# DATA for  B
ENG1=3; ENG2=10; ENG3=8; ENG4=7; ENG5=40; ENG6=38
echo -n "Correct is B -- Answer is = "; SCORETYPE

# DATA for  C
ENG1=12; ENG2=9; ENG3=6; ENG4=9; ENG5=32; ENG6=50
echo -n "Correct is C -- Answer is = "; SCORETYPE

# DATA for  D
ENG1=12; ENG2=9; ENG3=9; ENG4=8; ENG5=32; ENG6=50
echo -n "Correct is D -- Answer is = "; SCORETYPE
```

result of script

root@proxy:/tmp# vi multiple_var_test && ./multiple_var_test

Correct is A -- Answer is = A

Correct is B -- Answer is = A

Correct is C -- Answer is = A

Correct is D -- Answer is = A

Comment: you probably meant to use && instead of || ... the if else conditions don't make sense with the or || operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `((` instead of `[[` in order to evaluate arithmetic expressions.

You also need to use `&&` (and), not `||` (or) in your conditions.

Try this:

```
function SCORETYPE {
if (( ENG1 < ENG2 && ENG3 < ENG4 && ENG5 > ENG6 )); then
    STYPE="A"
elif (( ENG1 < ENG2 && ENG3 > ENG4 && ENG5 > ENG6 )); then
    STYPE="B"
elif (( ENG1 > ENG2 && ENG3 < ENG4 && ENG5 < ENG6 )); then
    STYPE="C"
else
    STYPE="D"
fi

echo "$STYPE"
}
```

(Note: Within an arithmetic expression, it is not necessary to prefix variables with a `$`.)

Answer (score 0):

You have your logic wrong - should be AND not OR, and you need to substitute your comparison operators with the below:

```
function SCORETYPE {
if [[ "$ENG1" -lt "$ENG2" && "$ENG3" -lt "$ENG4" && "$ENG5" -gt "$ENG6" ]]; then
    STYPE="A"
elif [[ "$ENG1" -lt "$ENG2" && "$ENG3" -gt "$ENG4" && "$ENG5" -gt "$ENG6" ]]; then
    STYPE="B"
elif [[ "$ENG1" -gt "$ENG2" && "$ENG3" -lt "$ENG4" && "$ENG5" -lt "$ENG6" ]]; then
    STYPE="C"
else
    STYPE="D"
fi

echo "$STYPE"
}
```